# Changing from layout view to data view using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, layouts

Is there a way to change from layout view to data view using Python and ArcMap 10?

I would prefer to do it using ArcPy.

Comment: Just curious, what's the use case for wanting to do this?

Comment: I originally wanted to do this because in ArcMap 10 the buttons to switch to layout or data view disappear sometimes. I thought I could simply change it using Python, but I still haven't been able to. It's not a solution to the problem, but I was more interested in learning how to do this in python anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
mxd.activeView = "my_data_frame_name"
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Answer (score 8):

To go the other way is as easy as:

```
arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("current").activeView = "PAGE_LAYOUT"
```

Comment: Thank you. I see the mention of "PAGE_LAYOUT" now in the online documentation. I appreciate you pointing this out. It's the last thing I needed for porting a 60-page mapping tool written in VBA and ArcObjects to a 10-page tool written with Python and arcpy. Plus, I can also take advantage of data driven pages. Thanks again!