# Changing from data view to layout view using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, layouts

[Changing from layout view to data view using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2249/changing-from-layout-view-to-data-view-using-arcpy), has been asked and answered, but I can't figure out how to switch to the layout view from data view using ArcPy and ArcMap 10.

Can it be done?